# Error with username/password checker

Tags: python, python-3.x

My assignment is to design a Python program that will allow one of three users (Alice, Bob, and Charles) to input a desired password. My program will determine if it is a valid password or not. In addition, my program should also check to see if that user has already used this password in the past, and return an error message if they have used it before.

I have successfully written the username and password conditionals, but cannot get the code to return an invalid/valid message when the user has or has not already entered the password.

```
user = input("Which user is this? ")
if user == "Alice" or user == "Bob" or user == "Charles":
    print("Welcome, ",user,"!",sep="")
else:
    print("I don't recognize that username. Please try again.")

def checkPassword(pw):
    errorMessage = ''

if ((len(pw) > 20)):
    errorMessage += "--Password is too long. 20 characters is the max.\n"
elif (len(pw) < 12):
    errorMessage += "--Password is too short. 12 characters is the min.\n"

if pw.isalpha():
    errorMessage += "--Password needs at least one digit.\n"

if pw.isdigit():
    errorMessage += "--Password needs at least one letter.\n"

if pw.isupper():
    errorMessage += "--Password needs an uppercase character.\n"

if pw.islower():
    errorMessage += "--Password needs a lowercase character.\n"

if pw.isalnum():
    errorMessage += "--Password needs a punctuation character.\n"

return errorMessage

passwordCandidate = input("Please input a valid password: ")
errors = ''

errors = checkPassword(passwordCandidate)

 if errors is not '':
    print("Your password is invalid:\n", errors, sep='')

elif user == "Alice" and passwordCandidate == "IamAlice123!" and 
passwordCandidate == "Alicerules99!" and passwordCandidate == 
"ILo^eBob2017" and passwordCandidate == "pa%%word2017":
    print("--It appears that you have used this password before. Please 
choose another one.")

elif user == "Bob" and passwordCandidate == "MyNameIs808,FearMe" and 
passwordCandidate == "hackerdude2017@@@" and passwordCandidate == 
"iamthe#1bestatLIFE" and passwordCandidate == "2Busy2BeTiedDown!":    
    print("--It appears that you have used this password before. Please 
choose another one.")

elif user == "Charles" and passwordCandidate == "Alice5uxAlice5ux!" and 
passwordCandidate == "GoAwayYuckyAlice" and passwordCandidate == 
"!secretlyLuvBob99" and passwordCandidate == "MarryMeB0b@~~~":
    print("--It appears that you have used this password before. Please 
choose another one.")

else:
    print("Your password is valid.")
```

[Photo of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/017PW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `and` operator to an `or` operator for the already used passwords, and enclose that in parenthesis.

```
elif user == "Alice" and (passwordCandidate == "IamAlice123!" or passwordCandidate == "Alicerules99!" or passwordCandidate == "ILo^eBob2017" or passwordCandidate == "pa%%word2017"):
   print("--It appears that you have used this password before. Please choose another one.")
```